# Taking consideration for advertisements in web design

Tags: website-design, client-relations

Can't argue that advertisements are an extra means of a web site generating income but should web designers take advertisements into consideration when laying out the pixels for a site?  Should this be discussed in a design brief?  How can you determine when advertisements are enough?  Is their a ratio to consider when adding advertisements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would definitely depend on the brief, but you never really know if any site will eventually need to resort to ads, so it's better to be prepared.

What I usually do is plan (even if it's in my head!) where those ads could be. There are some common places - both literal and metaphorical :). Main container, top banner, left-side menu, right-side menu... you should consider you might need to add elements in these places and design accordingly.

Google's Ad Sense has some [nice guidelines on ads placement](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1282097?hl=en). Some worth mentioning are choosing ad styles that are easy for your users to read, defining **Ad Units** and keeping the ads looking like ads. There are also some penalized practices to consider, like [too heavy ads in the top](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-page-layout-penalty-14612.html).

I don't think there is a ratio, it really depends on the type of site. Some pages highly depend on ads, so you will need to design around them, rather than having them as add-ons. [This article](http://footballmedia.com/ad-placement-tips-examples/) also seems to have some nice examples. Like Ad Sense mentions, sometimes less is more. Keep your ads looking like ads, and make sure there is a balance between ads and content, and you should be in the right path.